# SYSDATE minus some date variable returns a different value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle 11g and having a problem in finding the difference of days between two dates - (Sysdate) and some date variable. The difference then would be multiplied to another number. Below are the two methods I have tried but kept returning a negative value.

The newly assigned `return_date` variable has a correct value.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
UPDATE borrowed_books
    SET penalty_fine = (TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') - TO_DATE(return_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')) * 20,
        return_date = SYSDATE
        WHERE patron_id = patID AND
              transaction_id = transID;
```

```
UPDATE borrowed_books
       SET penalty_fine = (sysdate - return_date) * 20,
           return_date = SYSDATE
           WHERE patron_id = patID AND
                 transaction_id = transID;
```

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery like i used below.

```
CREATE TABLE BORROWED_BOOKS
AS
SELECT 5 PENALTY_FINE,TO_DATE('19000101','YYYYMMDD') RETURN_DATE,1 
PATRON_ID,78 TRANSACTION_ID FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 PENALTY_FINE,TO_DATE('19000101','YYYYMMDD') RETURN_DATE,2 
PATRON_ID,79 TRANSACTION_ID FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 PENALTY_FINE,TO_DATE('19000101','YYYYMMDD') RETURN_DATE,3 
PATRON_ID,80 TRANSACTION_ID FROM DUAL  

UPDATE BORROWED_BOOKS
   SET PENALTY_FINE =
        (SELECT (SYSDATE - RETURN_DATE)* 20
           FROM BORROWED_BOOKS
          WHERE PATRON_ID = 1 AND TRANSACTION_ID = 78)
      ,
   RETURN_DATE = SYSDATE
 WHERE PATRON_ID = 1 AND TRANSACTION_ID = 78;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured out the error as well.